# submit type button not able to submit the form in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, forms

I'm new to react and not getting what wrong with my project structure or code and not able to trigger the submit event for the form.

Below is the function I would like to call from form mentioned below.

```
handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        console.log('calling');
    event.preventDefault();
    const resp = await axios.get(`https://example.com/${this.state.userName}`);
    this.props.onSubmit(resp.data);
    //this.setState({ userName: '' });
  };

<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input 
      type="text" 
      value={this.state.userName}
      onChange={event => this.setState({ userName: event.target.value })}
      placeholder="GitHub username" 
      required 
    />
    <button>Add card</button>
    </form>
```

When I start the server and try to submit the form and tried various ways of doing that as mentioned below.

```
<input type='submit'/> 
<button onClick='submit'> Submit </button>
```

Click is not calling the handler function. Can anyone take a look and guide me here?

also, is there any alternative for forms in react like using div tag instead?#
You can check all code at -  https://github.com/tukaram57/react.git

Comment: Hi Tukaram. Instead just adding the whole code by github link, it's better to add the relevant stack of code using the SO tools.

Comment: Sorry, will take care next time

Answer (score 0):

You just forget to add 
`type='submit'` to the button

(Sorry if it is bad formatted but I'm on mobile)

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> 
///code
 <button type='submit'>Add card<button>     
</form>
```

Comment: Tried already with that option including <input type ="submit" />, but it's not working